# Count how many files starts with the same first characters c#

Tags: c#, winforms, io

I want to make function that will count how many files in selected folder starts with the same 10 characters.

For example in folder will be files named File1, File2, File3 and int count will give 1 because all 3 files starts with the same characters "File", if in folder will be

```
File1,File2,File3,Docs1,Docs2,pdfs1,pdfs2,pdfs3,pdfs4
```

will give 3, because there are 3 unique values for `fileName.Substring(0, 4)`.

I've tried something like this, but it gives overall number of files in folder.

```
int count = 0;

foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(folderLocation))
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);

    if (fileName.Substring(0, 10) == fileName.Substring(0, 10))
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Any idea how to count this?

Comment: `if (fileName.Substring(0, 10) == fileName.Substring(0, 10))` - For what value of `fileName` could this ever possibly be `false`?  It sounds like you want to track some information about your data *outside* the scope of the loop.  For example, perhaps a list of "file name substrings" which have already been encountered.  And then only increment the counter if you find something that hasn't already been encountered.

Comment: That comparison will always yield true (for file names 10 or more characters long). Use a container, e.g. hash table or tree to store the key (what you are comparing) then look the next one up and see if it exists, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instantiate a list of strings of files with a unique name, and check if each file is in that list or not:

```
int count = 0;
int length = 0;
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(folderLocation))
{
    boolean inKnown = false;
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
    for (string s in list)
    {
        if (s.Length() < length)
        {
            // Add to known list just so that we don't check for this string later
            inKnown = true;
            count--;
            break;
        }
        if (s.Substring(0, length) == fileName.Substring(0, length))
        {
            inKnown = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!inKnown)
    {
        count++;
        list.Add(s);
    }
}
```

The limitation here is that you are asking if the first ten characters are the same, but your examples given showed the first 4, so just adjust the length variable according to how many characters you would like to check for.

Answer (score 5):

You can try *querying* directory with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

...

int n = 10;

int count = Directory
  .EnumerateFiles(folderLocation, "*.*")
  .Select(file => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))
  .Select(file => file.Length > n ? file.Substring(0, n) : file)
  .GroupBy(name => name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
  .OrderByDescending(group => group.Count())
  .FirstOrDefault()
 ?.Count() ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

@acornTime give me idea, his solution didn't work but this worked. Thanks for help!

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(folderLocation))
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
            list.Add(fileName.Substring(0, 10));
        }
        list = list.Distinct().ToList();
        //count how many items are in list
        int count = list.Count;
```

Comment: Ah yes I forgot about the Distinct method, Glad I was able to help you draw the correct conclusion.